# CSS Syntax for children that are not direct descendents?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The question I want to ask is, "Is it possible/good practice to refer to a child of an element that is not a direct child?"

For instance, if you have HTML like this:

```
<form class="formation">
   <p>
      <span>
         <input class="phone input">
      </span>
   </p>
   <p>
      <span>
         <input class="text input">
      </span>
   </p>
</form>
```

And you want to refer in CSS to the inputs only in that particular form, so you call the class of the form followed by the class of the inputs without referring to the elements in between, like this:

```
.formation .input {
    width: 10px;
}
```

will this work properly?

I tend to think I've done this already on projects and it has worked properly but usually I refer to all the children in between (because I don't go that deep). But I'm currently working on a media query for a wordpress site that doesn't seem to be respecting this rule. Is this bad practice? Or is this downright incorrect? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Yes it will work. And yes it is the correct way to do it. I'm not entirely sure that this question needed to be asked. Any tutorial on the internet would show that this correct

Comment: that's just fine.. but if your really worried about it, just give them a unique class instead of using a parent/child selector

Comment: By definition, children are direct descendants, so the question does not make sense. You meant to ask for CSS syntax for descendants that are not children. And obviously you know the answer but you have some completely different problem somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is not only possible but also advisable to do so. Choose your selectors for your css rules as lean as needed to reduce dependency on your markup structure. This is not only wise for performance reasons, it also saves you quite some work in case your markup should ever change, e.g. later on you notice the span is not needed any longer and you remove it to keep your markup as clean as possible. In case you used the full DOM path to your .input you will then also have to adjust your css selectors. Same if for any reason in the future your <p> should become a <div>.

Just make sure you give the rules as much DOM context as necessary to not apply your rules to the same classed element in other contexts (if you have any at all, and if you want to apply a different set of style rules for it).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it'll work fine. What youv'e got with `.form .input` allows for any number of intermediate nodes between the two classes.

If you'd had `.form > .input`, then your CSS wouldn't match at all. `>` is the "immediate descendant" selector, so

```
.form .input { color: green }
.form > .input { color: red }

<div class="form">
   <div class="input">This is red</div>
   <div class="whatever">
      <div class="input">This is green</div>
   </div>
</div>
```